# URLの正規表現を用いた置換を教えてください

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

`<a class="url" href="https://hoge1/123456789/hoge2/">123456789</a>`

こういうモノがあったとして、『hoge1』と『hoge2』を書き換えたいのですが
『123456789』はランダム英数字になるので

```
var target, i, l = document.links.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  target = document.links[i].href;
  document.links[i].href = target.replace(/hoge1\/123456789\/hoge2\//, "hoge3/123456789/hoge4/");
}
```

これでは出来ません
そこで置換の際の英数字(123456789)を置換後にも持って行きたいのですがどうすれば良いですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ランダムな数字"は`[0-9]+`の正規表現で"数字1桁以上"として表せ、この部分を`()`で囲んでおくと置換部分にて`$1`で参照することができます。`()`のペアが増えるたびに`$1`, `$2`と数字部分が増えていく。
まとめると、

```
target.replace(/hoge1\/([0-9]+)\/hoge2\//, "hoge3/$1/hoge4/");
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに動作しました。
『\1』で動作してくれなくて悩んでいたのですが『$1』だったんですね…

Comment: `$1`は「置換部分」で参照する場合、`\1`の方は「パターンマッチ」の部分で参照する場合にそれぞれ使います。

Comment: 大変お勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。